# How to Access Object Binaries in .NET 4?

Tags: .net, serialization, object, binary

I need to read objects binary data (including private fields) to process and serialize them in a specific way.

How can I do this in C#, do I need MSIL coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using reflection and (optionally) dynamic IL generation.

For example, once you know the type (i.e. have a `System.Type` instance), you can enumerate all fields (`type.GetFields()` returns a list of `FieldInfo` objects), and then use `GetValue` method to get field value. This works with private fields, as long as the security trust level checks are passed.

This is not very fast, so you may want to precompile the field access code (only do that after the profiler tells you!). In this case, you can use `System.Reflection.Emit` and `DynamicMethod` facilities. (you can find the tutorials on Google and on MSDN; I found it helpful to compile some functions that do what I have to do with C#/F# and then inspect the MSIL output in Reflector/ildasm).

Comment: Any good books on emitting/customizing/manipulating MSIL code at compile- and run-time ?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any; the emitting is more or less straightforward using MSDN docs and Reflector. The only problem is that if your MSIL is incorrect (i.e. stack imbalance or improper types or something else), there is no detailed explanation, just an exception "something went wrong", so you have to double- and triple-check and guess. So I'd recommend trying to write some code - you'll get it very soon without books, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's quite easy. If you just want to read binary data (not serialized objects, but raw binary data), you can use `BinaryReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Start by implementing ISerializable.  That interface allows you to control serialization manually: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx

Comment: I'm wondering how protobuf-net is doing it ? It seems they are adding some MSIL code automatically for attributed classes